# load values from datasets into arrays and use them in a datastep

Tags: sas

I have  5 separate datasets(actually many more but i want to shorten the code) named dk33,dk34,dk35,dk51,dk63, each dataset contains a numeric field: surv_probs. I would like to load the values into 5 arrays and then use the arrays in a datastep(result), however, I need advice what is the best way to do it.

I am getting error when I use the macro: setarrays: (code below)

> ```
> WARNING: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 characters long.  You might have unbalanced quotation 
>          marks.
> WARNING: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 characters long.  You might have unbalanced quotation 
>          marks.
> ERROR: Illegal reference to the array dk33_arr.
> ```

Here is the main code.

```
%let var1 = dk33;
%let var2 = dk34;
%let var3 = dk35;
%let var4 = dk51;
%let var5 = dk63;
%let varN = 5;

/*put length of each column into macro variables */
%macro getlength;
%do i=1 %to &varN;
proc sql noprint;
     select count(surv_probs)
     into : &&var&i.._rows
     from work.&&var&i; 
quit;
%end;
%mend;

/*load values of column:surv_probs into macro variables*/
%macro readin;
%do i=1 %to &varN;
proc sql noprint;
select surv_probs 
into: &&var&i.._list  separated by "," 
from &&var&i;
quit;
%end;
%mend;

data _null_;
call execute('%readin');
call execute('%getlength');
run;

/* create arrays*/
%macro setarrays;
%do i=1 %to 1;
j=1;
array &&var&i.._arr{&&&&&&var&i.._rows};
do while(scan("&&&&&&var&i.._list",j,",") ne "");
&&var&i.._arr = scan("&&&&&&var&i.._list",j,",");
    j=j+1;
    end;
%end;
%mend;


data result;
%setarrays
put dk33_arr(1); 
* some other statements where I use the arrays*
run;
```

- Answer to toms question:

*macro getlength(when executed) creates 5 macro variables named: dk33_rows,dk34_rows,dk35_rows,dk51_rows,dk63_rows

*the macro readin(when executed):creates 5 macro variables dk33_list,dk34_list,dk35_list,dk51_list,dk63_list. Each containing a string which is comma separates the values from the column: eg.: 0.99994,0.1999,0.1111

*the macro setarrays creates 5 arrays,when executed, dk33_arr,dk34_arr,... holding the parsed values from the macro variables created by readin

Comment: It looks like you want to do some matrix manipulation. Do you have a license to use PROC IML?

Comment: Before you attempt to create macros to generate SAS code you should make sure you know what SAS code you want to generate.  Can you show an example of the working  SAS code that you want your macro(s) to generate?

Comment: I tried using a proc IML statement but I am getting ERROR: Procedure IML not found. @Tom

Comment: I answered your questions above @Tom

Comment: Maybe Instead of using arrays I can use what was created by macro readin to access the  values i need

Comment: Work the other way around. Instead of writing a macro and then showing what you think the macro generates. Write the SAS statements you want to run and then think about how you could do something that will make it easier to generate that program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that "macro arrays" like VAR1,VAR2,.... are generally more trouble than they are worth.  Either keep your list of dataset names in an actual dataset and generate code from that.  Or if the list is short enough put the list into a single macro variable and use %SCAN() to pull out the items as you need them.

But either way it is also better to avoid trying to write macro code that needs more than three `&`'s.  Build up the reference in multiple steps.  Build a macro variable that has the name of the macro you want to reference and then pull the value of that into another macro variable.  It might take more lines of code, but you can more easily understand what is happening.

```
%let i=1 ;
%let mvarname=var&i;
%let dataset_name=&&&mvarname;
```

Before you begin using macro code (or other code generation techniques) make sure you know what code you are trying to generate.  If you want to load a variable into a temporary array you can just use a DO loop. There is no need to macro code, or copying values, or even counts, into macro variables. For example instead of getting the count of the observations you could just make your temporary array larger than you expect to ever need.

```
data test1 ;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    do i=1 to nobs_dk33;
      array dk33 (1000) _temporary_;
       set dk33 nobs=nobs_dk33 ;
       dk33(i)=surv_probs;
    end;
    do i=1 to nobs_dk34;
      array dk34 (1000) _temporary_;
       set dk34 nobs=nobs_dk34 ;
       dk34(i)=surv_probs;
    end;
  end;
* What ever you are planning to do with the DK33 and DK34 arrays ;
run;
```

Or you could transpose the dataset first.

```
proc transpose data=dk33 out=dk33_t prefix=dk33_ ;
  var surv_probs ;
run;
```

Then your later step is easier since you can just use a SET statement to read in the one observation that has all of the values.

```
data test;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    set dk33_t ;
    array dk33 dk33_: ;
  end;
  ....
run;
```